# Android countdown timer even on device off

Tags: android, countdown

Hi I would like to ask if anyone knows how to make a countdown timer that is connected to the device and in the internet than even if you turn off the device, the countdown timer still goes on. if you know any source code relating to this question exists please help me to better understand the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "timer that is connected to the device and the internet"? you must clarify your question if you expect reasonable answers. Start with phrasing your question as an actual question.

Comment: sorry about that it's hard to explain, but in short it's like the energy in most game in android that it is restored every few mins even if the game is off or the device is off

Comment: if you cannot explain, how can you assume that others can provide the correct answer? This is why your question is now on hold...

Answer (score 2):

Be clear all TIMER TASK or ALARM task are cleared of queue once device is re booted or turned off, hence people need to re register there timers and alarms once device is booted back.

Having said that, with android existing provided functionality, you cant acheive what you are intending to, however with little extra effor you can do the same. first when device is switched off, any code is of no use its as good as dead, what you need is to save current state of all timers when you start them, now unless device is switched off, your logic will work accordingly, so to handle the exception you need to register an boot receiver, once device is rebooted you calculate the time lapsed in between, apply logic to valdate if timer is still valid and take action accordingly.

Apart then this, you cant do any other thing.

Comment: its like in games the energy part is restored even if you close the game right? and Is it not restored on device off?

Comment: Excatly, you need to save the last know state, when user closes your app or shuts the device down. When user start the task, just validate validity of data, and take the apporpriate action.'